# js: firebase access via very slow network times out

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, latency

Is there a way to increase timeout for the firebase auth and RT database? I was testing a response of the JS webapp with custom throttling mimicking poor satellite connection of 32kbps 1200ms latency and it times out occasionally. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain a little further. Are you using any CDN for static delivery? Any cache or Node purging?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid static delivery will be eventually be via firebase hosting but at the moment not. No cache. I'm sorry I don't know what 'node purging' is. Static content load never times out, only firebase auth. Regards.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Any updates?

Comment: Need a Firebase Engineer to explain why the connection is slow - but realistically, what traffic will you get with low connectivity?